# Programmatically align TextView inside TableRow

Tags: android

I'm creating TextViews and TableRows programmatically and I'm trying to align one of the TextViews (the one named Status: 1) to the right within the TableRow.

Current result:
[image: Text]


Expected result:
[image: Text]

Code:

```
TableRow tr = new TableRow(getContext());
tr.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

ImageView profileImage = new ImageView(getContext());
profileImage.setLayoutParams(new TableRow.LayoutParams(128, 128));
TextView usernameText = new TextView(getContext());
TextView friendStatus = new TextView(getContext());

tr.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
friendStatus.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); // It's not pushing the textview to the right?

usernameText.setText(username);
usernameText.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

friendStatus.setText("Status: " + status);

tr.addView(profileImage);
tr.addView(usernameText);
tr.addView(friendStatus);
tableLayout.addView(tr);
```

The TableLayout, reffered to as tableLayout is hardcoded in XML.

```
  <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        >
        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to stretch columns to make TextView full width by `android:stretchColumns="2"`

```
    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:stretchColumns="2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TableLayout>
```

Comment: Thank you, it now works as expected.
If anyone else run into this problem, this solution works but you still have to set the gravity by code. setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT); in my case.

Comment: Sure, I agree we have to call `setGravity` or `setTextAlignment`